# How to pass input to a command from file in Bash

Tags: windows, bash, vbscript, git-bash

In Git Bash, I ran the following command :

```
git pull --rebase
```

Now it prompts for `Username` & then `Password`

How to write a script such that the input required is automatically taken from a file.

I've already tried :

```
git pull --rebase <pass //did not worked
```

Of course, the `git credentials helper` & `config` solutions are fine, but I'm looking for a generic way for a command to read input from a file.

Comment: This might not be the best example - I don't know the `git` source but certain programs, most notably `OpenSSH`, bypass `stdin` and read directly from the `TTY` device when prompting for a password in which case redirection doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, I'm on windows. I wrote a `windows vbscript` to do the task for me.

Here's what the code looks like :

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim oEx
Set oEx = oShell.Exec("git stash")
Do Until oEx.Stdout.AtEndOfStream
    WScript.Echo oEx.Stdout.ReadLine()
Loop

WScript.Echo
WScript.Echo
WScript.Echo "=================Pull Rebase==================="
Dim oExPull
Dim tempString
Dim foundConflict
foundConflict = 0
Set oExPull = oShell.Exec("git pull --rebase")
Wscript.sleep 100
oShell.SendKeys "username{ENTER}"
oShell.SendKeys "password{ENTER}"
Do Until oExPull.Stdout.AtEndOfStream
    tempString = oExPull.Stdout.ReadLine()
    WScript.Echo tempString
    If foundConflict<=0 Then
        foundConflict = InStr(tempString,"CONFLICT")
    End If
Loop

If foundConflict=0 Then
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Echo "=================Stash Pop==================="
    Dim oExStashPop
    Set oExStashPop = oShell.Exec("git stash pop")
    Do Until oExStashPop.Stdout.AtEndOfStream
        WScript.Echo oExStashPop.Stdout.ReadLine()
    Loop
Else
    WScript.Echo "============Conflict Found ========================="
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a generic way for a command to read input from a file.

- `my_command < file` makes the *contents* of the path `file` the standard input of `my_command`.
- `my_command <<< value` makes the *string* `value` the standard input of `my_command`. This could also be a variable substitution like `my_command <<< "$variable"`.

[More about redirection.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection)

Comment: tried `<` & `<<<` - didn't worked, command used was `git pull --rebase` and input was username & password. Cause may be the buffer is cleared.

Comment: finally ended up writing vbscripting.

Comment: Really looking for trouble, in other words?

Comment: why do you say so! ? Please explain. I do not want to get in trouble for using vbscript.

Comment: It's a personal preference. Bash is one of the worst languages I've ever used (it's good for portability and ease of file reading/writing), and VBScript is even worse. Novice Bash developers can be excused for not knowing about `set -o errexit`, but the VBScript community seems to be built around *explicitly* ignoring errors using `On Error Resume Next`. Then there's the terrible documentation.